# Why does JSoup remove element IDs?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm using JSoup to sanitize some untrusted HTML. I discovered that if I call

```
String html = "<div id='foo'><script type='text/javascript'>alert('hello');</script></div>";
String cleanedHtml = Jsoup.clean(html, Whitelist.relaxed());
```

At this point `cleanedHtml` is

```
<div><div>
```

So the `<script>` tag has correctly been removed, but mysteriously, so has the `id` attribute of the `<div>`. Is there any good reason why this should be removed or is it a bug?

Comment: Try putting something else besides the `script` element inside the `div`.

Comment: It's all in the javadoc http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html

Comment: @BalusC (Actually, it isn't :( The Javadocs don't match the code--according to the docs, `<div>` tags should be removed, and it only states "appropriate" attributes, which leaves readers unsure, IMO. Creating pull requests.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the `id` attribute is removed; add it as an allowable attribute:

```
Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.relaxed().addAttributes("div", "id");
System.out.println(Jsoup.clean(html, whitelist));

=> <div id="foo"></div>
```

Is it a bug? Not AFAIC; it's in the source. IMO there are documentation bugs, though.

Is there "any good reason" why this should be removed? Not sure about that one, but attributes like this aren't structural: removing it doesn't alter the DOM. That's the thing about whitelists–they explicitly allow, and must be curated to match your precise needs.