# How to remove the attributes in div tag without class,id and style rest of attributes need to be delete using coldfusion?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have attribute like this. 
Example:

```
<div class="issue-document" id="assr_0335-5985_1991_num_76_1_1619" itemprop="hasPart" itemscope="" itemtype="https://facebook.com>

<cfset mystring = 'This is some text. It is true that <div class="issue-document" id="assr_0335-5985_1991_num_76_1_1619" itemprop="hasPart" itemscope="" itemtype="https://facebook.com">Harry Potter</div> is a good, but is better'>
<cfset MyReplace = ReReplaceNoCase(mystring,"<div [^>]*>","","ALL")>

<cfoutput><pre>Original string: #mystring# 


Without link: #myreplace#</pre></cfoutput>
```

I need to remove only itemscope and itemprop like this rest of the attribute like id,class, style i don't want to remove using coldfusion in regular expression. Can any one please help to find the solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: this much only i tried i am not familiar with regex .

Comment: Are there other elements w/itemprop & itemscope that you want retained?
I've remove targeted attributes from specific elements within HTML fragments using ColdFusion & jsoup. It requires selecting all div nodes and removing the itemprop & itemscope attributes if they exist. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18248084/693068

Comment: i have one doubt can any one help me if supppose i need remove all attributes in div means what i can do

Comment: Can you remove that with JavaScript with `removeAttribute`?

Comment: i need to remove all attributes using regex only in coldfusion

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfset myReplace = reReplaceNoCase(mystring, '\b(itemscope|itemprop)="[^"]*"', "", "all")) />
```

https://trycf.com/gist/8d84d7d355f7c54e5533eeed22d097ba/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: can you please tell me how to remove all attributes without mention the attribute

Comment: i believe you change need to change the (itemscope|itemprop) to \w+